# "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Attempting to Defer

Tags: jquery, pagespeed

I received "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error when I use defer.

Q. How can I defer this script correctly? the code is

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
              $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
          } else {
              $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
          }
      });
      $('.scrollup').click(function () {
          $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop: 0
          }, 600);
          return false;
      });
  });
  </script>
<!--end-->
```

Comment: CDN is OK ...problem is inside the <script> code </script> ..btw ..why defer ???

Comment: You would have to delay all scripts that depends on jQuery library to execute or load after jQuery. Pretty complicated. Leaving jQuery as is (without defer) is the simplest solution.

Comment: If You want to defer some scripts, do it on other scripts. But keep in mind, that scripts loading order due to defer can cause other errors.

Comment: This particular script is a back to to top so after ones scroll down the page. So It's not critical and I wish to help with page speed. @RohitasBehera

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case You can use `setInterval()` function to wait until jQuery is ready.

```
function start_scripts(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
              $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
           } else {
              $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
           }
       });
       $('.scrollup').click(function () {
           $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop: 0
           }, 600);
           return false;
        });
    });
}

var jQ_interval = setInterval(function(){

    if(typeof jQuery == 'function'){
        clearInterval(jQ_interval);
        start_scripts();
    }

}, 300); // You can change 300 to other delay
```

But I wouldn't recommend this approach if there is more code to execute. Better solution is to not defer jQuery, but other scripts.

Comment: This is pretty unreliable—what if jQuery takes more than the given interval to load? What if it takes much less?

Comment: This is not pretty I admit, but it won't hurt user CPU if we run simple if statement every 300 ms. If jQuery load take less than 300 ms this is not a problem at all. Delay is unnoticeable.

Comment: It’s pretty kludgy. If you’re gonna go through the work of using `defer` you shouldn’t really have any inline scripts. This also will hide errors if jQuery never loads for some reason, since it will never fail—just keep silently retrying—making debugging difficult.

Comment: I know. I'm no coder but the way Squarespace codes looks pretty Mickey Mouse. I'm trying to improve page speed for mobile. Thanks.

Comment: This is simple script and as OP said in comments - this code is used only for "back to top" functionality. That is the only reason why I propose this solution. There is no need to prove that this is bad. It's just enough for this task.

Comment: Q. If I copy the query from "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js and create file to load internally, will that speed up much?

Comment: @CallMeNicholi Kind of... If You use CDN there is a chance that user/users won't have to download jquery, because they'll have in browser cache already. But if You scan website with some tool like: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ there will be no difference.

Comment: The best option is to put all scripts to the bottom of the page. Just before closing <body> tag

Answer (score 0):

[`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) results in that script not being run till after the document has been parsed. If other scripts after it depend on that script (in this case, depend on jQuery), they should also have `defer` added to them (the load order is preserved when using `defer`) else they may load *before* the earlier `defer`ed script.

If you have inline scripts which depend on a `defer`ed script, you’ll have to move them to an external file (and add `src` & `defer`), as inline scripts cannot be deferred.

Comment: Can you take a look at the page? I'm not a coder. https://www.thehangoutrestaurant.com/

Comment: @CallMeNicholi Looking at the page doesn’t change anything. As described: you have an inline `<script>` (one without a `src`) which depends on a `defer`ed script. You should either remove the `defer` or move the inline script to a separate file and include it `<script src="/path/to/thatfile.js" defer>`. Inline scripts are discouraged, anyway.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, part of the site is coded in a way that I can't access. I believe that file is {squarespace-headers}

Comment: To be honest, if you don’t have much control over the site, I wouldn’t use `defer`. Move the `<script>` for jQuery (and all others) as close to the end of `<body>` as possible and that’s likely “good enough” from a performance perspective. `defer` is a bit more optimal, but if the script isn’t critical it doesn’t matter much.